# How to make a conditional update on records based on level changes in MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables like below :

User_details :

```
Id `referal_id`    `fk_user_id`  `promotion_level`

1   `0`             `1`             `1`
2   `1`             `2`             `1`
3   `1`             `3`             `1`
```

promotion :

```
ID  `promotion_level`

1  `member`
2  `Team Lead`
3  `manager`
```

I want to update the promotion level in User_details table based on the following conditions :

1) If the referal person having two users means update the promotion level of referal person to  team lead.

2) In both the users ( referal person having ) having two , two users individual means update the promotion level of Users to " Team Leader" and the referal User promotion level to "manager".

For Example :

If the fk_user_id  1 having two users so update the promotion level of fk_user_id  to "Team Lead".

and the both users  ( 2 & 3 ) having two two users means update the promotion levels of 2 & 3 to " Team Leader"  and update the promotion level of fk_user_id  1 to "manager".

If fk_user_id 2 only having two user means  update promotion level of fk_user_id   2 only.

please Give me any idea in sql queries .  I am trying like below :

```
<?php

  $query = "select count(fk_user_id) as user_count,promotion_level from   user_details where referal_id = 10 ";

  $res = mysql_query($query);

  $user_id = [];
   while($row=mysql_fetch_array($res)){

  $count = $row[user_count];
  $level = $row[promotion_level];
  echo $count;
  echo $level . '<br>';

  }

  if(($level==1) && ($count==2)){

   $update_que=mysql_query("update user_details set promotion_level=2 where fk_user_id='10'");



   }
  ?>
```

Comment: Hi Nisanth. We try to not write code for people, but rather help with problems when you encounter them. Can you show us any code you have attempted, or make your question for specific (such as something like: how do a conditional update on a table)?

Comment: This also doesn't sound like a PHP issue, but a mysql issue.